# Not sure what the sql query is doing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am just an intern so please don't judge me. I for the life of me can't understand what the following query is doing:

```
"select id as cat,category_name from category where  parent_id='0' and child_id='0' and exim_code!='0' and dis_status='1' group by category_name asc"
```

This is a live website that i have been asked to analyse the code for, so  i am just reading the code not really testing it. Below is the entire code snippet.

```
$cat = isset($cat)?$cat:'';
echo $drop->get_dropdown($db,"select id as cat,category_name from 
category where  parent_id='0' and child_id='0' and exim_code!='0' and            
dis_status='1' group by category_name asc",$MS_Categ);
```

Comment: I don't blame you for not understanding what the code does. It's hard to tell really. At a glance I'd say it removes duplicate `category_name` rows in the least useful way imaginable

Comment: Any time you see a group by without any aggregation functions you have to suspect a fudge, and a possible non determinate result.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah the code is a bit of a mess. Without many comments or useful notes. It's giving me a really hard time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @P.Salmon is fudge a technical term? I need to know what to google. Thanks.

Comment: `group by category_name asc` - should that not just throw an error due to the `asc` that does not belong there …?

Comment: @04FS can u please elaborate what u mean. It's a live website, and i have not seen any error message

Comment: @04FS in mysql it **was** allowed as a shortcut to an order by

Comment: @hakiko after i have learned what a database is from the link u gave, where do u think i should move from there so that my question is answered. Since u think i don't understand even the most basic fundamentals of database and its terminologies?

Comment: Please give any DDL involving that table.

Comment: @philipxy not sure how that will help?

Comment: Why does that matter? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select id as cat, category_name
from category
where parent_id='0' and child_id='0' and exim_code!='0' and dis_status='1'
group by category_name asc
```

This query selects from the category table, and filters all results where the parent_id is 0 and the child_id is 0, and the dis_status is 1, but the exim_code does not equal 0.

Once it has done the filter, it then groups everything by the category name. In other words, if there where 10 results for "clothing", it will only return one of them.

It then returns the id field, renamed as 'cat', and the category name.

Since the query does not group by the id field, the id can be any id with the associated category_name.

I assume this is all done to get a valid ID that links to a unique category_name, so that it can be put in a drop down with the ID as the value, and the category name as the text. My assumption is that any ID that is linked to that category will do.

**EDIT:** Add explanation of Group By

The Group By groups similar records together, only returning one of each. For example, given the following data:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | category_name |
|----+---------------+
|  1 | A             |
|  2 | B             |
|  3 | C             |
|  4 | B             |
|  5 | B             |
|  6 | A             |
+----+---------------+
```

The results of the above query would return something like:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | category_name |
|----+---------------+
|  1 | A             |
|  2 | B             |
|  3 | C             |
+----+---------------+
```

The ID fields aren't guaranteed which it will return, it could also return:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | category_name |
|----+---------------+
|  3 | C             |
|  4 | B             |
|  6 | A             |
+----+---------------+
```

But it will only return one of each category.

Comment: Its the group by statement that's tripping me. If it's any help the drop down menu in the actual website is showing the  options alphabetically. Do u think it's that what it's doing?

Comment: The group by groups similar results together, I will update my answer to include that

Comment: Also, just to add, this does not sort the data alphabetically. The fact that you're seeing the data listed alphabetically means its either alphabetical in the table, or being sorted programmatically afterwards, either in PHP, or in JS after page render.

Comment: Wow thanks! that's really helpful. So, basically what it does is removes duplicate values and then arranges them in ascending order.

Comment: Ok. Got it about the ascending order bit i guess i would have to dig a little deeper into the code to look for that. Thanks again